# Morphia and Shared fields in collection documents contain different types of data

Tags: java, morphia

I have a collection and documents in it, have the same fields. But some fields have different types. For example, the "Role" field is an array of objects in first document and a regular array in second. How does Morphia work with such examples? How can I read the document from the database?

If the Role field is the same type in all documents (the query type `Query query = datastore. createQuery (ScheduleData .class); List schedules = query.find().toList();`) works very well. If different:

```
error java.lang. RuntimeException: java.lang. ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to declare those fields as `Object` in your entity.  Morphia will/should decode in to the correct type before assigning to the field but there's no common parent type of `String` and `Document` other than `Object`.